# sql server management studio express 2014 not enumerating network sql servers

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, visual-studio-2015

In my apps, I am using **SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()** to enumerate the sql servers on local networks.

I had **VS 2010 pro** and **Sql Server 2008 R2 Express** and **SSMS 2008 R2 Express** and **VS 2013 Pro**. Everything was ok. Then I installed **VS 2015 Community Edition**, removed **VS 2013 Pro**. Then my apps and SSMS starts return nothing for enumarating sql servers on local network.
Then I removed (uninstalled through Programs and Features) every thing related with **Sql Server 2008 R2 Express**  and re-installed it, but this time installed the **SSMS 2014 Express Edition** not SSMS 2008 R2 Express.

Now I have **VS 2010 Pro** (that I should keep it at least for a while) and **Sql Server 2008 R2 Express** and **SSMS 2014 Express** and **VS 2015 community Edition**.
Even If I built my apps with **VS 2010 Pro** or **VS 2015** targeting to .Net 4.0, my apps can not enumarate the sql servers. **SSMS 2014** can not either.
But on the command line **osql -L** and **sqlcmd -L** enumarating the sql servers on my local network. **SSMS 2014** can see the my **local Sql Server 2008 R2** and connect seamlessly.

I did things with sql server configuration manager to enable tcp/ip and named pipes enable, default port to 1433, login mode to mixed etc. Even be sure that windows firewall is allowing the sql ports and sql server browser is running.

What can be the reason that I can not numerate the sql servers with **SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()**  and SSMS also can not see the network sql servers?

Comment: -same application runs normal on a different computer which has no .net 4.6

Comment: .Net 4.6 has a bug which broke all 4.x runtime versions of GetDataSources. Please let MS know that you're having this problem also so they'll fix it:
[Microsoft connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1582568/sqldatasourceenumerator)

Answer (score 0):

Same Issue here. I enumerate SQL Servers with SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources() and right after installing *VS2015 Enterprise* the call always returns nothing. I have *SQL Server 2014 Enterprise* installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Framework issue. If you set your application target framework to Net 3.5 then `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` works. I̶'̶m̶ ̶s̶t̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶l̶o̶o̶k̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶a̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶a̶r̶o̶u̶n̶d̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶N̶e̶t̶ ̶4̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶h̶i̶g̶h̶e̶r̶.̶  - Its a bug

Although the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) article states for only SQL 2000 ~ 2005, It does say Net  4.6, 4.5, 4 are supported.

**Added**

[Its been reported as a bug for Windows 10 & Net 4.x](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1633740/system-data-sql-sqldatasourceenumerator-doesnt-work-on-windows-10-with-net-framework-4-x)

Comment: Although the MSDN article states for only SQL 2000 ~ 2005, I have been enumerating sql server 2000  ~ 2014   with my c# app targeting to Net 4.0. Unfortunately, setting my app target to Net 3.5 is not an option for me. Since It has been reported as  a bug to Microsoft, we need to wait for them to resolve the issue hopefully A.S.A.P.